# email composer does not go back when i click cancel

Tags: ios

so heres my problem i have mad an action  sheet added in twitter and Facebook which work fine however when i added in an email composer it seems that the application is unable to to go back to the original screen and stays in the email composer.

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

//Each button title we gave to our action sheet is given a tag starting with 0.
if (buttonIndex == 0) {

    //Check Twitter accessibility and at least one account is setup.
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Switcher makes social networking easier, download it now from (LINK):D "];

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have logged into twitter aleady from your iphone settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

    //Check Facebook accessibility and at least one account is setup.
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *facebookSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
        [facebookSheet setInitialText:@"Switcher makes social networking easier, download it now from (LINK) :D "];

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [self presentViewController:facebookSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a post right now, make sure you have logged into facebook aleady from your iphone settings" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }

}else if (buttonIndex == 2) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSString *email = @"";
    NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email,nil];
    NSString *message = @"hey download my application now";
    [mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
    [mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
    [mailContoller setSubject:@""];
    [self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` method. You need to dismiss the mail composer yourself in that method.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:controller completion:nil];
}
```